# How to keep track of Cassandra write successes while using Kafka in cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, frontend

When working in my cluster I have the constraint that my frontend cannot display a finished job until all the jobs different results have been added into Cassandra. These result are computed in their individual microservices and sent via Kafka to a cassandra writer.

My question is if there are any best practices for letting the frontend know when these writes have completed? Should I make another database entry for results or is there some other smart way that would **scale well**?

Each job has about 100 different results written in to it, and I have like 1000jobs/day

Answer (score 1):

I used Cassandra for a UI backend in the past with Kafka , and we would store a `status` field in each DB record, which would very periodically get updated through a slew of Kafka Streams processors (there were easily more than 1000 DB writes per day).

The UI itself was running some `setInterval(refresh)` JS function that would query the latest database state, then update the DOM, accordingly.

Your other option is to push some websocket/SSE data into the UI from some other service that indicates "data is finished"

Comment: Okay, does that mean you first wrote a blank record then? Which would be updated when an actual record would be inserted.

Comment: It could be blank, but no, we implemented a kind of state machine DAG that included states of QUEUED, PROCESSING, PROCESSED, and ERROR, for example

Comment: This repo does something similar using Kafka Streams rather than Cassandra https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/hello-streams